# Upgrading Windows XP to Vista to Windows 7

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, upgrade

Okay I am trying to do an in-place upgrade Windows XP to Windows 7, via Vista, but I am running into a problem.

I put my Vista disc in for the initial upgrade but when I get to the part where it asks if I want an Upgrade or a Clean install, the upgrade option is greyed out, and there is a message on the bottom that says the following:

```
Upgrade has been disabled.
-Windows cannot determine if another operating system is exists on your computer. 
Try repairing the boot configuration and then begin the installation again.
```

Can someone tell me why this is hapening and how to fix it?

Also, it is Windows XP Pro, to Windows Vista Business, to Windows 7 Pro, all 32bit which I checked the upgrade paths and this should work...

Comment: You are trying to install Windows Vista from within Windows right?  I would contact Microsoft for assistance.

Comment: Yes... I am trying to install Vista from withing Windows...

Comment: Have you tried repairing the boot configuration?  Should be a simple enough process, boot into the Recovery Console, use a command which is harmless if there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Am I supposed to use just "a command" randomly?

Comment: Repairing the boot configuration is a seperate problem.  You didn't indicate if you already tried that.  I was just indicating the command that does repair the boot configuration is harmless if it doesn't require repair.

Comment: I am asking what the appropriate command would be as no, I have not ran it.

Comment: Easier to point to something somebody else wrote then duplicate the same content. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/483/xp_repair_fix_master_boot_record_recovery_console/

Comment: That did not work...

Comment: You fixed the master boot record. As the MBR corrupt or did the command basically do nothing?

Comment: It said it was a non-standard boot configuration so I told it to "fix" it, but I still have the same issue...

Comment: Did you happen to write down what it said exactly? As indicated in an answer, which raised a valid question, have you tried the upgrade assistance tool?  If the tool did something it means something is going on with the MBR.  Do you know if its this is actually licensed installation of Windows XP?

Comment: This does not work on windows xp